# Let's Encrypt gives 404/502 for acme-challenge but in browser 200

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot

I cannot renew my Let's Encrypt SSL with completely same server configuration as I did before.

The most strange thing that happens is that I can access the acme-challenge in my browser.

But Let's Encrypt considers it as 404/502:

[image]

I'm using the `init-letsnecrypt.sh` script (before the same worked for me)

I have tried to change:

- My docker configuration
- My server configuration
- Issue the certificate in:

  - staging
  - production
- Trying with different modes of certbot like:

  - manual
  - webroot
- etc.